# How do I center table text both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've seen similar or maybe even same questions but I've tried the solutions and it didn't work for me.

I'm trying to create a table that would center the text vertically and horizontally idealy using flex which for me totally destroys the entire table structure when using "d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center. Also it's important that the first blocks from the left have the extended width!

I'm trying to achieve something similar or same as the table on this website "https://media.realestate.com.au/ad-specs/ad-unit/home-page-hero/"

Here's my code

```html
<div class="row my-4 bg-white">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light">Ad unit</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">buy</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">rent</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">sold</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">news</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">guides</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">lifestyle</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">video hub</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">find agents</h6></th>
                    <th><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">new homes</h6></th>
                </tr> justifa
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><h6 class="font-weight-light">Home Page Hero</h6></td>
                    <td class="bg-green"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
ul a{
    color: #8ec302 !important;
    text-underline: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
a{
    color: inherit !important;
    text-underline: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
#navigation a:hover{
    color: #8ec302 !important;
    text-underline: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
#navigation a{
     color: inherit !important;
     text-underline: none !important;
     text-decoration: none !important;
 }

.footer-hyperlink-hover  a:hover{
    color: #8ec302 !important;
    text-underline: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.image-no-resize {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 350px;
}
.card-header {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.card {
    border: none !important;
}
h6{
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}
ul h6{
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}
span{
    font-weight: bold;
}
/*End of styling*/

/*Pictures*/
.career-picture{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/career.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
}
/*End of pictures*/

/*Spacing*/
.container-fluid-short{
    max-width: 100rem;
    width: 100%;
}
.container-fluid-shorter{
    max-width: 65rem;
}
.container-fluid-shorter-inner{
    max-width: 76rem;
}
```

I've tried setting the custom width on the left myself which did work but stopped after my recent tweaks I've made to the code. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Please provide your css changes as well, then it will be easier for us to respond.

Comment: Ago I will in a moment!

Comment: Done I've updated the post with my css.

Comment: I don't see any CSS class added in Html matching with declared CSS classes

Comment: When using `display: table-cell;`, you can align vertically with `vertical-align: middle;` and horizontally with `text-align: centre;`. Why do you need to use flex? Secondly, using `h6` is semantically redundant inside a `thead`. You may find it easier to style without those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `text-center align-middle`. Also, set the first column of each row to `<th scope="row"></th>`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row my-4 bg-white">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"><h6 class="font-weight-light">Header</h6></th>
                    <th scope="col"><h6 class="font-weight-light">Header</h6></th>
                    <th scope="col"><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">Header</h6></th>
                    <th scope="col"><h6 class="font-weight-light text-capitalize">Header</h6></th>
    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><h6 class="font-weight-light">Home Page Hero</h6></th>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                    <td>Default</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">Center Everything</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```